# Array list not adding values

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

I am trying to make a dictionary with words and definitions. I have made a 2d array list to store the words and the definitions for each word. It looks like this:

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> dictionary = new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>();
    String input = "";
    int pos, i = 0;
    do{
        System.out.print("Enter 'add' to add word and definition, 'remove' to remove a word and its definition, 'change' to change the definition of a word, or 99 to quit: ");
        input = sc.nextLine().toLowerCase();
        switch(input) {
            case "add":
                while(dictionary.size() < 1) {
                System.out.println("Enter word: ");
                input = sc.nextLine();
                ArrayList<String> def = new ArrayList<String>();
                System.out.println("Enter definition to add: ");
                input = sc.nextLine();
                dictionary.get(i).add(input);
                i++;
                }
                break;
            case "remove":
                System.out.print("Enter word to remove: ");
                System.out.println(dictionary);
                input = sc.nextLine();
                ArrayList<String> remove = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(input));
                pos = dictionary.get(remove);
                if(dictionary.contains(input)) {
                    dictionary.remove(pos);
                    System.out.println("removed " + input);
                }
                else {
                    System.out.println("Word is not in dictionary");
                }
                break;
            case "change":
                System.out.print("Enter word to change: ");
                System.out.println(dictionary);
                input = sc.nextLine();
                pos = dictionary.indexOf(input);
                System.out.println("Enter replacement word: ");
                String replacement = sc.nextLine();
                //replace word (haven't implemented yet)
                break;
```

I am having trouble with adding the new definition to the array. I have tried the code above but it keeps returning a blank array whenever I run it.

Is there a way I can return an array list with the added definitions and words?

Also, how can I get the position of an inputted string into a String ArrayList?

Answer (score 0):

> How can I get the position of an inputted string into a String ArrayList

Given an `ArrayList<AnyObject>` you can do the following

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<>(List.of("A","B","C"));
int idx = list.indexOf("B");
System.out.println(idx + " " + list.get(idx));
```

Prints

```
1 B
```

However, have you considered using a Map<String,String> ?

```
Map<String,String> dict = new HashMap<>();
dict.put("House", "A dwelling or place to live");
dict.put("Cat", "a pet");

System.out.println(dict.get("Cat"));
```

prints

```
a pet
```

Now change it

```
dict.put("Cat", "A type of animal");
System.out.println(dict.get("Cat"));
```

prints

```
A type of animal
```

Comment: Note that `List::of` requires Java ≥ 9.

Comment: True -- but still, generics requires Java >= 5 but I don't remember anyone saying that, ever.  And we're almost at Java 16!

Comment: I know. Somehow I feel that many organizations are stuck at Java 7 or 8, but I never heard of someone being stuck at Java 4.